# Arrange movie clips from an array into grid as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The following code is intended to load movie clips from an array onto the stage and arrange them into a grid formation.

I get the following error:

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert animal1$ to flash.display.MovieClip.
```

(code used from answer provided by Andrew Sellenrick)

```
var columns = 4;
var rowHeight = 50;
var columnWidth = 1000;
var currentRow = 0;
var currentColumn = 0;
var animalCards = [animal1, animal2, animal3, animal4, animal5, animal6, animal7, animal8, animal9];

for (var i = 0; i < animalCards.length; i++) {

    var card = animalCards[i];
    card.x = currentColumn * columnWidth;
    card.y = currentRow * rowHeight;
    addChild(animalCards[i]);

    currentColumn++;
    if (currentColumn == columns) {
        currentRow++;
        currentColumn = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. What kind of MovieClips? What do you expect the grid to look like or do?

Comment: Arranging element in a grid pattern is a very simple math problem involving only addition in it's most basic implementation.

Comment: I have searched google, but nothing i found addresses my specific need. I am a novice so i will try to code somthing in order for you to see the direction i am trying to go in. Then, i will update my question for clarity.

Comment: See updated question above.

Comment: @Warren What's the type of your `animal1` object ? You can try to cast it to MovieClip using for example : `MovieClip(animal1)` ...

Comment: @Warren The code you posted will **not** produce the error you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just off the cuff, you will have to take it and make it work for your needs.

```
var columns = 4;
var rowHeight = 50;
var columnWidth = 50;
var currentRow = 0;
var currentColumn = 0;
var listOfMovieClips = [clip,clip,clip,...];

for (var i = 0 ; i < listOfMovieClips.length ; i++){

   var mc = listOfMovieClips[i];
   mc.x = currentColumn * columnWidth;
   mc.y = currentRow * rowHeight;
   addChild(listOfMovieClips[i]);

   currentColumn++;
   if (currentColumn == columns){
      currentRow++;
      currentColumn = 0;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This is definately what I am trying to do.  However, I think I got something wrong when trying it out.  See the revision to my question above.

Comment: Is Animal a class you have made? Make sure it extends MovieClip.

Comment: Where are all the types in this code? AS3 makes it optional but it's certainly not a good practice to omit them. Example `var columns` should be `var columns:int`, and `var listOfMovieClips` should be `var listOfMovieClips:Array` or `var listOfMovieClips:Vector.<MovieClip>`, and `var mc` should be `var mc:MovieClip` or at least `var mc:DisplayObject`.

Comment: Don't forget that you should create a variable for listOfMovieClips.length so that the value isn't checked every loop...